# How to use Spring RestTemplate to scroll and filter using date range in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the Elasticsearch REST API to scroll the results and filter them based on a date. Using cUrl, the following statement gives me the desired results:

```
curl -d '{"query":{"range":{"timestamp":{"gte":"2017-01-27T13:23:11"}}}}' "http://127.0.0.1:9201/logs-test*/_search?pretty=true&size=5&scroll=1m"
```

But I have not been able to get the same behaviour while making the request using Spring RestTemplate, where I am getting all the results and no filtering gets applied. This is what I have in my Java code:

```
// content type
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
// header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);         
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String body = "{\"query\":{\"range\":{\"timestamp\":{\"gte\":\""+ sdf.format(dateObject) +"\"}}}}";
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);
// request
ResponseEntity<String> result =
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: What happens if you use `HttpMethod.POST` instead?

Comment: Thank you Val, seems like Elasticsearch accepts both GET and POST request in such cases. I got it working now.

Comment: Yes, but it's a good practice to use POST when sending a payload.